# Parsing xml using NSData

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, nsxmlparser, nsdata

I am working with cocoa, I want to parse an xml file.
But there are 2  warnings in my code here

`incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct NSURL *' when passing argument 1 of 'initWithContentsOfURL:' from distinct Objective-C type` 
and `class 'XMLParser' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol`

this is my code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:@"/Users.xml"]; // here is the first warning
    // create and init NSXMLParser object
    NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    // create and init our delegate
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    // set delegate
    [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser]; // here is the second warning

    // parsing...
    BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse];

    // test the result
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"No errors");// - user count : %i", [parser [users count]]);
        // get array of users here
        //  NSMutableArray *users = [parser users];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");
    }

    [parser release];
    [nsXmlParser release];
    [pool drain];

    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

How can I solve this please ? when i run , it tells me that the program received signal SIGABRT and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is an NSURL class... you need to pass one of these, just like the warning says.

And don't set the delegate of the parser to the parser itself. If you don't need a delegate, simply don't set one. Delegates are used for callbacks, so your application gets to manipulate things during the parsing.

Comment: if (success) {
    NSLog(@"No errors");// - user count : %i", [parser [users count]]);
    // get array of users here
    NSMutableArray *users = [parser users]; // How do I parse here parser is a XML PArser not an NSXML Parser ??

Answer (score 0):

initWithContentsOfURL: requires a [NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as a parameter not a file name so you need to construct one from the file name e.g.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users.xml"];
```

You do not need the NSdata so directly do

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users.xml"]];
```

When you set the delegate the object you delegate to must implement say it implements the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol - in the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html) it sets the delegate to itself and not the XMLParser for doing nothing extra, in other examples the delegate implements those methods it needs.

See the [SeismicXML example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Listings/Classes_ParseOperation_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323-Classes_ParseOperation_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

The delegate is declared as
`@interface ParseOperation () <NSXMLParserDelegate>` and implements some of the methods in NSXMLParserDelegate

So in your case you would need `@interface XMLParser () <NSXMLParserDelegate>` and implement the methods you want.

Comment: thx, I thought that using nsdata can be useful later because i want to display the data from the xml into a combobox

Comment: and what about the nsXmlParser ?

Comment: if (success) { NSLog(@"No errors");// - user count : %i", [parser [users count]]); // get array of users here NSMutableArray *users = [parser users]; // How do I parse here parser is a XML PArser not an NSXML Parser ??

Comment: The XMLParser has to implement the methods from NSXMLParserDelegate that you want - equivalent to the ParseOperation in the example

Comment: would you please write the correct code . this makes me mad :(

Comment: Mark , my application is to parse data from an xml file and display them in a combobox , whould you help me please to do this

Comment: Start with one of the Apple Examples or another tutorial e.g. http://devcry.heiho.net/2012/03/parsing-xml-with-nsxmlparser.html